# Сортировка данных по полю на сайте

Tags: python, django

У меня есть список сотрудников, и я хочу сделать выбор сортировки на странице сайта по полю. Как это сделать?

`models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models


class RegionalDirector(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    start_work = models.DateField()
    payment = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class RegionalManager(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    start_work = models.DateField()
    payment = models.IntegerField()
    chief = models.ForeignKey(RegionalDirector,
                              blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='regionaldirector_worker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class Head_of_warehouse(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    start_work = models.DateField()
    payment = models.IntegerField()
    chief = models.ForeignKey(RegionalManager,
                              blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='regionalmanager_worker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class Brigadier(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    start_work = models.DateField()
    payment = models.IntegerField()
    chief = models.ForeignKey(Head_of_warehouse,
                              blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='Head_of_warehouse_worker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class Worker(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    start_work = models.DateField()
    payment = models.IntegerField()
    chief = models.ForeignKey(Brigadier,
                              blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='Brigadier_worker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

`views.py`:

```py
import itertools

from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from worker.forms import WorkerFilterForm
from worker.models import *


worker_form = WorkerFilterForm(request.POST)

def index(request):
    director = RegionalDirector.objects.all()
    manager = RegionalManager.objects.all()
    head_of_house = Head_of_warehouse.objects.all()
    brigadier = Brigadier.objects.all()
    worker = Worker.objects.all()
    workers = list(itertools.chain(director, manager,
                                   head_of_house, brigadier,
                                   worker))
    paginator = Paginator(workers, 20)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'worker/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки, передавайте параметр, например в `GET` запросах.

Получайте в нем как надо отсортировать, например: `order_by = request.GET.get('ordering') or 'id'`

И при получение `QuerySet` работников сортируйте через `order_by` метод `worker = Worker.objects.order_by(order_by)`

---

Совет - перед тем как спрашивать - поищите в интернете, иначе вероятность что ответят будет низкой. Многие ответы на вопросы уже есть на первых позициях по запросам

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы мне очень помогли. Я нашел нужную мне информацию, но на момент создания вопроса не поинмал как это реализовать.